# Add message to Azure Service Bus Queue from SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, azure, triggers, message-queue

I have a SQL trigger on one of my database tables and would like to add a message to my Azure Service Bus Queue when the SQL trigger is executed.

Does anyone has a SQL code example of how to do this?

It's worth mention that SQL will be running in a SQL database which is running in Azure.

Please do not start a discussion of the question of using SQL triggers or not this is purely get working SQL code for the question above.

Answer (score 4):

It's not clear if your SQL is running on a VM or SQL Database. What you could do is create a CLR Stored Procedure and call the Azure Service Bus through REST APi.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqllive/2008/06/18/accessing-rest-based-web-services-using-sql-clr/

Azure Service Bus Queue through REST API

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/queues

Comment: This approach is implemnted in details here: https://jsomers.be/archive/2018/12/20/sending-messages-to-azure-from-sql-server-part-1/

Comment: @HenrikGering that link is broken, do you have an updated one?

Comment: No, it seems to be completely gone. It described the porcess of creating an assembly that could be called in a trigger. To be honest, i think you are better off creating a table for the massages, and create a seperate service that polls the table and sends the messages.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could look into [debezium](https://debezium.io/) it is a seperate service, but it might suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented an Azure SQL and Service Bus solution (also a solution for Event Grid) using a logic app with a SQLserver trigger new additions to a table, standard store procedures then generate relevant JSON payloads and stores it in the table where the logic app has a trigger on. When a JSON payload is written to the table the logic app is fired, and sends the payload to a service bus queue or topic or event grid topic - works like a charm.

Comment: Hi Jonas, Could you elaborate on how you implemented this? Did you make a REST call to the ServiceBus, or did you use the assembly directly?