# Send message to Azure ServiceBus from SQL

Tags: sql-server, azureservicebus

I want to send messages to the Azure ServiceBus from SQL Server through a stored procedure.
I've come across several solutions which requires me to install software from other vendor, which I don't want to do.

The only solution so far seems to use Common Language Runtime Integration in which .NET (Framework) code runs as a stored procedure. I'm not sure if this is the way to go.

Comment: Could you use SQL Service Broker to raise an event and have a C# application receiving the messages and forwarding onto Azure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have the following options:

1. Use CLR to call [ServiceBusClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.servicebusclient?view=azure-dotnet)
2. Write the message into a queue implemented with a simple table or with SQL Service Broker and use another C# application to read from the queue (as suggested in the comments)
3. Build the request manually (see [Send Message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/send-message-to-queue)) and send it using a POST request from Powershell using [Invoke-WebRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-7.1) or [Invoke-RestMethod](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-7.1), executed with [xp_cmdshell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/xp-cmdshell-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)
4. Build the request manually and send it using a POST request with WinHttpRequest and sp_OACreate and sp_OAMethod (like it was done 10-15 years ago)

Also, think about why you want to use a stored procedure for this. Who is calling the stored procedure? If it's a trigger, then doing the POST request syncronously is a bad idea (but using a queue, especially with Service Broker, may be acceptable). If it's another client application, can you change it to call Service Bus directly?

Comment: Yes. We already have decided to use a Service Broker. But how to get messages from the queue to post them to a ServiceBus will be either CLR or polling with a C# application.

Answer (score 1):

You can think of below approaches:

**Approach 1**

1. Define table in the Azure SQL containing rows for the event
2. Using SQL connector of Logic apps, you can act on the inserts to the table.[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-sqlazure)
3. Using Azure Service bus connector of Logic App, you can send messages to Azure service bus. [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-servicebus)

**Approach 2**

1. Write a CLR Stored procedure, which is calling the Azure Service bus REST API. The steps are detailed in the [Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42661183/add-message-to-azure-service-bus-queue-from-sql#42661305)

Answer (score 0):

Hope following steps will help you to create CLR stored procedures to make Azure Service Bus call through REST API.

1. Write .NET code to make CLR stored procedures
2. Compile the code to make it as an assembly
3. Register the assembly in SQL Server
4. Create CLR stored procedures
5. Call REST based web services using the CLR stored procedures

The above steps are described in detail in the following link [Accessing REST based Web services using SQL CLR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sqllive/accessing-rest-based-web-services-using-sql-clr)

Answer (score 0):

if you too afraid of CLR integration (extra steps as well as external dependency on CLR library) then you can for your ease, call a powershell script from stored procedure to simplify things.

https://hubsqldba.wordpress.com/2013/07/31/call-a-powershell-ps1-file-from-a-stored-procedure/